# Can a quad-tree be used to accurately determine the closest object to a point?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quadtree

I have a list of coordinates and I need to find the closest coordinate to a specific point which I'll call P.

At first I tried to just calculate the distance from each coordinate to P, but this is too slow.

I then tried to store these coordinates as a quad-tree, find the leaf node that contains P, then find the closest coordinate in that leaf by comparing distances of every coordinate to P. This gives a good approximation for the closest coordinate, but can be wrong sometimes. (when a coordinate is outside the leaf node, but closer). I've also tried searching through the leaf node's parent, but while that makes the search more accurate, it doesn't make it perfect.

If it is possible for this to be done with a quad-tree, please let me know how, otherwise, what other methods/data structures could I used that are reasonably efficient, or is it even possible to do this perfectly in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm by [Hjaltason and Samet described in their paper "Distance browsing in spatial databases"](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emeesh/cmsc420/ContentBook/FormalNotes/neighbor.pdf). It can easily be applied to quadtrees, I have an implementation [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/blob/083e190b2b4d8989fa3e04592d0fb03d6260368b/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index/qtplain/QuadTreeKD0.java#L362).

Basically, you maintain a sorted list of pairs <distance, object>, the list is sorted by distance (closest first). The objects are either points in your tree (you call them coordinates) or nodes in the tree (distance to closest corner, or distance=0 if they overlap with you search point).

You start by adding the root node.
Then, to get the next closest point, you look at (and remove) the first entry in the list.
If the first entry is a node, add all points/subnodes from that node to the list and check the top of the list again. If the first entry is a point, it is automatically the next closest point in the quadtree.
You can simply repeat return points from the top of the list until you have as many closest points as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try "loose quadtree". It does not have a fixed volume per node. So it can adjust each node's bounding volume to adapt to the items added.

If you don't like quadtree's traversing performance and if your objects are just points, adaptive-grid can perform fast or very close to O(N). But memory-wise, loose quadtree would be better.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can find the closest coordinate inside a quad-tree even when it is not directly inside the leaf. in order to do that, you can do the following search algorithm :

1. search the closest position inside the quad-tree.
2. take its distance from your initial position
3. search all the nodes inside this bounding box from your root node
4. return the closest node from all the nodes inside this bounding box

however, this is a very basic algorithm with no performance optimizations. among other things :

if the distance calculated in 2. is less than the distance to the border of the tree node, then you don't need to do 3 or 4. (or you can take a node that is not the root node)

also, 3 and 4 could be simplified into a single algorithm that only search inside the tree with the distance to the closest node as the bounding box.

And you could also sort the way you search for the nodes inside the bounding box  by beginning to search for the nodes closest to your position first.

However, I have not made complexity calculation, but you should expect a worst case scenario on one node that is as bad if not worst than normal, but in general you should get a pretty decent speed up all the while being error free.